# How to create Model with nested object in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a small product manufacturing app with **Django**. There are two main **models** in the app.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

class ProductionOrder(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    entries = # not sure what goes here
```

I would like `ProductionOrder.entries` to be a list of dictionaries which include the `Product` and a `quantity` value.

The created `ProductionOrder` would appear as so (not exactly sure :

```py
productionOrder = {
   'id': 2, 
   'entries': [
      { 'product': 'product_1_ref', 'quantity': 10},
      { 'product': 'product_2_ref', 'quantity': 10}
   ]
}
```

How can I accomplish this in a correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a model in the middle that refers to the `ProductionOrder` and the `Product`, and you can span a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) to make filtering more elegant:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

class ProductionOrder(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        through='ProductOrder',
        related_name='orders'
    )

class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(ProductionOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

If you thus have two products `p1` and `p2`, and you want to add five items of `p1` and seven items of `p2` to an order `o1`, we can work with:

```
p1 = … # first product
p2 = … # second product
o1 = … # first order

ProductOrder.objects.bulk_create([
    ProductOrder(product=p1, order=o1, quantity=5),
    ProductOrder(product=p1, order=o1, quantity=7)
])
```